# Data from server is shown repeated on RecyclerView in NestedScrollView onScrolled

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I was trying to solve this problem but I'm getting stuck already.
I want to make the data fetched from server load continuously when the page scrolled to the bottom. But what I got is the data shown repeated.

This code sometimes show as expected, but sometimes not.
It runs like expected if I scroll slowly and wait for the next fetching, but if I do it fast, it will double the data fetched.

I want to make this page like instagram user profile, like scrolling our post.

**This is the layout**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_10"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_20"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_20"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_10">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/civ_user_photo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pol_avatar"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/casablanka"
                    app:civ_border_width="1dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_20"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/report_status"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_report"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_total_report"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/status_report"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_wait"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_total_wait"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/status_wait"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_complete"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_total_complete"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="@string/status_complete"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/btn_edit_profil"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/report_status"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_14"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_edit_profile"
                    android:padding="@dimen/padding_8">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/edit_profile"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/casablanka" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_20"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_20">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_4"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_2"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_2"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ic_loc"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/padding_20"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/padding_20"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_location"
                    android:tint="@color/gray183" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_user_location"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_2"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_10"
            android:background="@color/gray183" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_report_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_10"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_20"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_20"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_10"
            android:text="@string/status_report"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_16"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_6"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_empty_post"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_6"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/no_data_available"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_report"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/pb_load_more"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**This is the java file**

```
    public class ProfileFragment extends RxFragment implements ReportAdapter.ItemClickListener {

    @Inject
    QuackApiService quackApiService;
    @BindView(R.id.rv_report)
    RecyclerView rvReport;
    @BindView(R.id.civ_user_photo)
    CircleImageView civUserPhoto;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_username)
    TextView tvUsername;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_user_location)
    TextView tvLocation;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_total_report)
    TextView tvTotalReport;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_total_wait)
    TextView tvTotalWait;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_total_complete)
    TextView tvTotalComplete;
    @BindView(R.id.ll_empty_post)
    LinearLayout llEmptyPost;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_report_title) TextView tvReportTitle;
    String statusFilter = ProgressCons.ALL;
    @BindView(R.id.progress_bar) ProgressBar progressBar;
    @BindView(R.id.pb_load_more) ProgressBar pbLoadMore;
    @BindView(R.id.nested_scroll_view) NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;

    int numberColumnsGrid = 3;
    ReportAdapter adapter;
    int oldCount;
    String token, userId, afterId;
    Context context;
    RequestOptions avatarDeft;

    private boolean isLoading = false;
    private int pastVisibleItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount = 0;
    private int resultSize = 12;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private int count=0;

    public ProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
        setLayout();
        loadData();
        loadReportStatus();
        loadReport(statusFilter);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void setLayout(){
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), numberColumnsGrid);
        rvReport.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        rvReport.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        /*
        rvReport.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){
                    isLoading = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisibleItems = ((GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (isLoading && (visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems == totalItemCount)){
                    loadReportMore(afterId, statusFilter);
                    isLoading = false;
                }
            }
        });
         */
    }

    private void onScrolled(){
        nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener((NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener) (v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY) -> {
            if(v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1) != null) {
                if ((scrollY >= (v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight())) &&
                        scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                    isLoading = true;
                    visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                    pastVisibleItems = ((GridLayoutManager) rvReport.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (isLoading && (visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems == totalItemCount) && visibleItemCount >= ((count++)*resultSize)){
                        loadReportMore(afterId, statusFilter);
                        isLoading = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        loadData();

       /*
        try {
            if (adapter.getItemCount() != oldCount) {
                loadReportStatus();
                loadReport(statusFilter);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
        */
    }

    private void init() {
        context = getActivity();
        DaggerInit.networkComponent(context).inject(this);
        token = "Bearer " + Preferences.getToken().getAccessToken();
        userId = Preferences.getProfile().getId();
        avatarDeft = new RequestOptions();
        avatarDeft.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_pol_avatar);
        avatarDeft.error(R.drawable.ic_pol_avatar);
    }

    @OnClick({R.id.btn_edit_profil, R.id.civ_user_photo})
    public void editProfil() {
        EditProfilActivity.start(getActivity(), userId);
    }

    private void loadData() {
        User user = Preferences.getProfile();
        if (userId.equalsIgnoreCase(user.getId())){

            Glide.with(getActivity())
                    .setDefaultRequestOptions(avatarDeft)
                    .load(user.getPictureUrl())
                    .into(civUserPhoto);

            if (!user.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
                tvUsername.setText(user.getUsername());
            } else {
                tvUsername.setText(R.string.username_not_set);
            }

            if (!user.getAddress().isEmpty()) {
                tvLocation.setText(user.getAddress());
            } else {
                tvLocation.setText(R.string.loc_not_set);
            }

        } else {
            quackApiService.getUserProfile(userId)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(object -> {
                        if (object.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(ResponseCons.SUCCESS)){
                            User userProfile = object.getData();
                            Preferences.setProfile(userProfile);

                            Glide.with(getActivity())
                                    .setDefaultRequestOptions(avatarDeft)
                                    .load(userProfile.getPictureUrl())
                                    .into(civUserPhoto);

                            if (!userProfile.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
                                tvUsername.setText(userProfile.getUsername());
                            } else {
                                tvUsername.setText(R.string.username_not_set);
                            }

                            if (!userProfile.getAddress().isEmpty()) {
                                tvLocation.setText(userProfile.getAddress());
                            } else {
                                tvLocation.setText(R.string.loc_not_set);
                            }
                        } else {
                            civUserPhoto.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pol_avatar));
                            tvUsername.setText(R.string.username_not_set);
                            tvLocation.setText(R.string.loc_not_set);
                        }
                    }, error -> {
                        ErrorHelper.thrown(error);
                    });
        }
    }

    private void loadReportStatus(){
        User user = Preferences.getProfile();
        quackApiService.getUserProfile(userId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(object -> {
                    if (object.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(ResponseCons.SUCCESS)){
                        User userProfile = object.getData();
                        Preferences.setProfile(userProfile);
                        tvTotalReport.setText(String.valueOf(userProfile.getReportCount().getAllCount()));
                        tvTotalComplete.setText(String.valueOf(userProfile.getReportCount().getCompleteCount()));
                        tvTotalWait.setText(String.valueOf(userProfile.getReportCount().getWaitCount() + userProfile.getReportCount().getProcessCount()));
                    } else {
                        tvTotalReport.setText(String.valueOf(user.getReportCount().getAllCount()));
                        tvTotalComplete.setText(String.valueOf(user.getReportCount().getCompleteCount()));
                        tvTotalWait.setText(String.valueOf(user.getReportCount().getWaitCount()));
                    }
                }, error -> {
                    ErrorHelper.thrown(error);
                });
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.ll_report) public void getAllReport(){
        statusFilter = ProgressCons.ALL;
        loadReport(statusFilter);
        tvReportTitle.setText(getString(R.string.report));
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.ll_wait) public void getWaitReport(){
        statusFilter = ProgressCons.WAIT;
        loadReport(statusFilter);
        tvReportTitle.setText(String.format("%s %s", getString(R.string.report), getString(R.string.status_wait)));
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.ll_complete) public void getCompleteReport(){
        statusFilter = ProgressCons.COMPLETE;
        loadReport(statusFilter);
        tvReportTitle.setText(String.format("%s %s", getString(R.string.report), getString(R.string.status_complete)));
    }

    private void loadReport(String filter){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        quackApiService.getFilterPosts(userId, resultSize, filter)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(object -> {
                    if (object.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(ResponseCons.SUCCESS)){
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        List<Report> posts = object.getData();
                        adapter = new ReportAdapter(posts, this);
                        rvReport.setAdapter(adapter);
                        oldCount = adapter.getItemCount();
                        if (adapter.getItemCount() > 0){
                            llEmptyPost.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            int count = object.getData().size() - 1;
                            afterId = object.getData().get(count).getId();
                            onScrolled();
                        } else {
                            llEmptyPost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        llEmptyPost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }, error -> {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ErrorHelper.thrown(error);
                });
    }

    private void loadReportMore(String nextId, String filter){
        pbLoadMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        quackApiService.getFilterPostMore(userId, nextId, resultSize, filter)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(object -> {
                    if (object.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(ResponseCons.SUCCESS)){
                        pbLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        List<Report> posts = object.getData();
                        adapter.addReports(posts);
                        int count = object.getData().size() - 1;
                        afterId = object.getData().get(count).getId();
                    }
                }, error -> {
                    pbLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ErrorHelper.thrown(error);
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onReportItemClickListener(Report report) {
        DetailActivity.start(getActivity(), report);
    }
}
```

Anyone's got idea to solve this problem?

Thanks before.

Comment: did you mean you implemented load more functionality in recycler view but its not working properly    ?

Comment: sometimes it working properly but sometimes not. It works properly if I scroll smoothly and must be very patient to scroll. But if I scroll it fast, like we did scroll in instagram, or line feed, it double the data

Comment: yes, they use load more functionality on the scroll time.(Y)
your issue was occurred when you load data in to adapter after getting success from API call.

Comment: so what i have to do to the adapter? create postdelay?

Comment: here is the link 
https://medium.com/@programmerasi/how-to-implement-load-more-in-recyclerview-3c6358297f4

note:- add progress indicator while you trying  to get data from server.

Comment: it worked if it recyclerview, but not for nestedscrollview. For the progress indicator, I've created it.

Comment: @IvanaNatalia did you find solution? If yes then pls upload solution. I have same problem.